# How do I properly hook to customize my WooCommerce shop page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am creating a theme from scratch and I have installed WooCommerce. However, I am trying to customize the product archive page. I specifically want to have a banner before any WooCommerce content. The code below is from my **functions.php**.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'shop_banner', 35);

function shop_banner(){
  echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';
}
```

When I call this hook, nothing happens.

But when I call the “*woocommerce_before_shop_loop*” hook, it works and displays the content (but this is not where I want the content to display).

I decided to test it and see if the hook worked anywhere else, so I added it to my **woocommerce.php** file. Below is the code when I added it.

```
<?php get_header() ;
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );?>

    <div class="container woocommerce p-5">

        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
    </div>




<?php get_footer() ?>
```

The content displayed when I did that. But I do not want it to be on every page, only my archive pages. So it seems it is hooking on just fine but it is *not* wanting to display on the **archive-product.php** page. The code below is the first part of my archive page, which was copied straight from the woocommerce template folder.

```
/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_main_content.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
 * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );

?>
<header class="woocommerce-products-header">
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php
    /**
     * Hook: woocommerce_archive_description.
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
    ?>
</header>
```

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated. Also I have only used WooCommerce for about a week so I am very new to the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition in your hook. Take a look to conditional tags on [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'shop_banner', 35);
function shop_banner(){
  if(!is_shop()){
     echo '<h1>Hello</h1>';
  }
}
```